# PHP parameter SEO Friendly

Tags: php, url, parameters, request, seo

I am using the current code on my website:

to request a pasge:

```
$content = $_REQUEST['p'];
```

to load the page:

```
<?
        if(file_exists('' . $content . '.php'))
            {
            require('' . $content . '.php');
            }else{
            require('error.php');
            }
?>
```

my url be like:

mywebsite.com/index.php?p=home

How can I make this more SEO friendly? Like:

mywebsite.com/home

Thank you.

Comment: "SEO friendly" is marketing BS.

Comment: Mightn't be SEO friendly, but definitely more user friendly to have /home - you need to look into URL rewriting for whatever webserver you're using

Comment: @Trent who types in urls? 99.999% are click's

Comment: You can use .htaccess to do that `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]`

Comment: @nogad, having urls like this, wont affect my performance on google rank?

Comment: @Mario, this code gave me a internal server error.

Comment: do you think google is so stupid? its the quality of your content that counts